# mysql select by id using between

Tags: mysql

I have a question on join two table

TWD_CSD_NEWS_DETAIL (200 million row):

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| CSD_ID    | CSD_ID_DRI | CSD_PARTY_ID | CSD_PARTY_AMOUNT |
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| 1         | 1          | 1183         | 27870            |
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| 2         | 1          | 1723         | 12               |
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| 3         | 1          | 1243         | 87474            |
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
.
.
.
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
| 18575622  | 8881       | 1183         | 27870            |
+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+
```

the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE TWD_CSD_NEWS_DETAIL`:

```
CREATE TABLE `TWD_CSD_NEWS_DETAIL` (
  `CSD_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CSD_ID_CREATED_BY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_DT_CREATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_DT_UPD` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_ID_DRI` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_ID_UPD_BY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_PARTY_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_AMOUNT` decimal(26,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CSD_TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSD_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=184035984 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

TWD_DRI_NEWS_RESULT_HEADER (1 million row) :

```
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| DRI_ID | DRI_DATE            | DRI_SYM_SYMBOL |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| 1      | 2011-11-08 00:00:00 | 1              |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2      | 2011-11-08 00:00:00 | 2              |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| 3      | 2011-11-08 00:00:00 | 3              |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
.
.
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| 10001  | 2011-11-11 00:00:00 | 8881           |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+
```

the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE TWD_DRI_NEWS_RESULT_HEADER :

```
CREATE TABLE `TWD_DRI_NEWS_RESULT_HEADER` (
  `DRI_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DRI_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DRI_SYM_SYMBOL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DRI_TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DRI_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1592193 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I try to join them with following sql, it works but it will take very long to completed this query when i keep adding csd_id range in `where` cluase

```
SELECT 
    csd.CSD_ID, csd.CSD_ID_DRI, csd.CSD_PARTY_ID, csd.CSD_AMOUNT ,  dri.DRI_DATE, dri.DRI_SYM_TICKER
FROM
    TWD_CSD_NEWS_DETAIL csd
        LEFT JOIN
    TWD_DRI_NEWS_RESULT_HEADER dri ON dri.DRI_ID = csd.CSD_ID_DRI
WHERE
   (  
     ( 
    ( csd_id between 1 and 426029) 
 || ( csd_id between 426030 and 851977) 
 || ( csd_id between 851978 and 1277890) 
   ..
...
...
     ) 
AND dri.DRI_SYM_SYMBOL = 1 

   )
```

do i need create another view to contain result or any faster method to query this? i tried with the range `between 1 and 200000000` ther duration and fetch time require 0.197 seconds / 26 seconds

Comment: Your  `WHERE` clause looks like one big range. Any reason why you're not doing `csd_id between 1 and 1277890` ?

Comment: "I try to join them with following sql, it works but it will take very long to completed this query" Are there indexes?  Show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output for all tables involved in the question.. Also give us the output off `EXPLAIN query`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a single range for your query?

```
 SELECT 
  csd.CSD_ID, csd.CSD_ID_DRI, csd.CSD_PARTY_ID, csd.CSD_SHAREHOLDING ,  
  dri.DRI_SHAREHOLDING_DATE, dri.DRI_SYM_TICKER
 FROM
  TWD_CSD_NEWS_DETAIL csd
 LEFT JOIN
  TWD_DRI_NEWS_RESULT_HEADER dri ON dri.DRI_ID = csd.CSD_ID_DRI
 WHERE
  csd_id between (1 and 1277890) AND dri.DRI_SYM_SYMBOL = 1;
```

Comment: fetch time will 0.197 and fetch time require 26 seconds

Comment: it works much faster when i add limit 1, 500, thx and either multiple range or single not effect the result much.